# Could we allow the creation of [iphone-4s] tag?

Tags: support, tags

I tried to create an iPhone 4S (iphone-4s) tag, but the system won't let me. I think it's a pluralization blocker (iMacs vs iMac). I was excited, because I've never created a tag before.

Can this one be allowed? It's obviously the right tag for the upcoming hardware, and y'all have decided posts about the 4S are on-topic now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is plural protection, which wasn't wanted in this case. Looks like a mod created the tag in the meantime.

Comment: Correct. I had been hoping to earn the Taxonomist badge, which thus didn't happen. But, as they say, oh well.